# "Select a File to Preview" window takes up half of screen when Windows Explorer is maximized

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I open Windows Explorer the window opens in only part of the screen with the "Select a File to Preview" box taking up a normal amount of space in it like this:[image]

But when I click the Maximize button to make Explorer fill all of the screen except for the taskbar area the "Select a File to Preview" box suddenly takes up almost half of the window like this:[image]

And I have to manually  resize it to make it normal the way I want it when it is Maximized like this:[image]
Furthermore, my fix is never permanent and it is always the same story with any new Explorer windows. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I am sorry if this seems like a simple question but I am stumped as to what to do.